# Routing a REST API in groups with Slim

Tags: php, rest, api, slim

I'm building a rest api with slim 3 but I'm having some trouble understanding how to do the routing. I initially had the get method working correctly at api.com/v1/companies/get and api.com/v1/companies/get/id and post method at api.com/v1/companies/post, but I refactored so all the methods would be at api.com/v1/companies/id and after this refactoring I get a 405 error on post requests saying that only the get method exists.

So I did a little more researching; the amount of small, but breaking inconsistencies I've found in other slim 3 guides has been a bit annoying, but it looks like my solution is the `map()` function, only I have no idea how to use it, and even the official docs skip over the part I don't understand.

This is how the code looked after the refactor that broke it:

```
$app->group('/v1', function() use ($app) {
    $app->group('/companies', function() use ($app) {
        $app->get('/{code}', function($request, $response, $args) {...}
        $app->get('', function($request, $response, $args) {...}
        $app->post('', function($request, $response, $args) {...}
    });
});
```

And my first attempts at using map():

```
$app->group('/v1', function() use ($app) {
    $app->map(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'], '/companies/{code}', function($request, $response, $args) use ($app) {
        //here's where I don't know what to do
        if($request->isGet()) {
            //What goes here? And I seem to be having problems accessing my parameters?
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->group('/v1', function() {
    $this->map(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'], '/companies/{code}', function($request, $response, $args) {

        if($request->isGet()) {
            $response->getBody()->write("it's GET");
        }

        if($request->isPost()) {
            $response->getBody()->write("it's POST");
        }

        if($request->isPut()) {
            $response->getBody()->write("it's PUT");
        }

        if($request->isDelete()) {
            $response->getBody()->write("it's DELETE");
        }

        return $response;
    });
});

$app->run();
```

Please don't use $app inside group. In [docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-groups) you can see that $this inside group point to instance of 'Slim\App' already. Also check your .htaccess file if it's configured as described in Slim3 documentation.

Comment: Right about the $this and $app, I think originally had it as $this but I kept seeing $app in other places. Thanks